# SQL relational database - table names in a table

Tags: sql

I have these tables

**DataType**

```
Name     TableName
-------------------
Animal   dataAnimal
Vehicle  dataVehicle
```

**dataVehicle**

```
ID      Name       Speed
-------------------
1       Car        10
2       Bike       2
3       Horse      4
```

**dataAnimal**

```
ID      Name       ImageFile
-----------------------------
1       Cow        cow.jpg
2       Sheep      sheep.jpg
3       Pig        pig.jpg
```

Is it possible to make a relationship with datatype column `TableName` and all the tables with that name?

Comment: Not entirely clear - are you asking whether it's possible to enforce that `TableName` in `Datatype` always contains the name of a table (and presumably, that table cannot be dropped whilst a row with it's name exists in `Datatype`)? Also, what database system?

Comment: :) Oded answered my question thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible in just about *any* SQL database.

Relations, table and column names are not dynamic - the only way to query based on this structure is to use [Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html), which is complex and comes with dangers like [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

You need to rethink your design or choice of persistence technology.